# DENY all traffic from other namespaces

Tags: kubernetes

I want to block all traffic from other namespaces with a simple Network Policy. But it doesn't give the result I want. Am I doing something wrong?

```
k get namespaces
prod              Active   39m
qa                Active   39m

k get networkpolicies.networking.k8s.io -n prod
NAME                         POD-SELECTOR   AGE
block-other-namespace        <none>         25m

k get -o wide pods --all-namespaces
prod          curl-pod    1/1     Running   0          47m   10.244.2.2     minikube-m03
prod          web         1/1     Running   0          47m   10.244.1.3     minikube-m02
qa            curl-pod    1/1     Running   0          47m   10.244.1.2     minikube-m02
```

The Network Policies yaml file is as follows.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  namespace: prod                         
  name: block-other-namespace
spec:
  podSelector: {}                          
  ingress:
    - from:
        - podSelector: {}
```

However, I can send requests to the pod in the qa namespace with the pod in the prod namespace.

```
kubectl -n qa exec curl-pod -- curl -I http://10.244.1.3
0HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.23.2
Date: Sun, 13 Nov 2022 08:34:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 615
Last-Modified: Wed, 19 Oct 2022 07:56:21 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "634fada5-267"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programmin, but networking-related, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Which SDN are you using? Not all SDN would support NetworkPolicies. Your "block-other-namespaces" looks good otherwise.

Comment: @SYN yes, that's the answer I was looking for. I found out that Minikube uses Kindnet by default and Kindnet does not support Network Policies.

Comment: @j4nus you can deploy minikube with network policy envofremcnt with `minikube start --network-plugin=cni` and then `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v3.24.1/manifests/calico.yaml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried recreating your environment, and the network policy configuration set works for me. Please make sure you have a CNI with support for enforcing network policies installed.

You can check out the [calico installation guide](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/getting-started/kubernetes/quickstart)
or install it in a one liner:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v3.24.1/manifests/calico.yaml
```

---

Also, we faced these kinds of issues at Otterize when manually configuring network policies to control access between pods. We ended up building a solution of our own and open-sourced it - https://docs.otterize.com/quick-tutorials/k8s-network-policies